# How can i get all valuese in an another Activity (Recycler View), whose were chosen by me

Tags: java, android

I need to send a value to Second Activity(with RecyclerView) and full it.
For example, there is a recyclerView in Main Activity and it works. I want to revise this action in second Activity and then i open a Second Activity i want to see there a filled recyclerView. Please. Help me!

This is my ArrayList,method and call the second activity.

```
worldList = new ArrayList<>();
    worldList.add("cat");//i want to display this word firstly
    worldList.add("dog");//it after click
    worldList.add("monkey");//after it
    worldList.add("bird");//after it
    worldList.add("fish");//etc
    worldList.add("home");//etc
    worldList.add("car");//etc




public void onClickYes(View view) {
    display.setText(worldList.get(i));
    progress.setText(counter + "");
    wordItems.add(new RecyclerItems(worldList.get(i)));
    builderAdapter();
    if (i < worldList.size()) {
        i++;
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Слова закончились", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

**My Second Activity**

```
public class YesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
//ArrayList<String> yesWordList;
///////////////////////////////////////////
final ArrayList<RecyclerItems> wordItems = new ArrayList<>();
///////////////////////////////////////////
//private WordDataBase wordDatabaseForYes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_yes);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String word = null;

    if(extras != null) {
        word = extras.getString("key");
    }

    wordItems.add(new RecyclerItems(word));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvYes);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(wordItems);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: You can add a boolean in RecyclerItems Model and initialise all of them false, then whenever an item of this List is set; turn its value to true. After that pass the arraylist as parcelable extra to new activity and filter from arraylist until true.
OR
You can also pass the index to next activity of last item which has been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the same recyclerview(save list of data) in two different activates, you could use a common View model.
Write codes to get the data from the view model. (write a getter method in the view model)
Then all you need to do is write codes to create an instance of view model in each activity and call the that method.

[Here is a useful article series](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel#0)